# “Empty Payload. JSON content expected” error calling Microsoft Graph to create Domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call the Microsoft Graph API to create a domain. Unfortunately when I go to make the call, I receive an error stating that the "JSON Payload is empty".

Here is the call I am making:

```json
GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient =
    new GraphServiceClient(new GraphAuthenticationHelper(NetOrgDomain));
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage =
    new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUri);

string content = "{\"id\": \"sampleDomainAdd.info\"}";
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
var jsonContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpRequestMessage.Content = jsonContent;

HttpResponseMessage response =
    await _graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an mix of Graph SDK and direct HTTP calls going on here. When using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), you should be using the objects it provides rather than attempting to roll your own.

It also greatly simplifies your code:

```cs
var domain = await graphClient.Domains.Request().AddAsync(new Domain
{
    Id = "sampleDomainAdd.info"
});
```

As an aside, the error you're getting currently is due to you're sending the data without the `content-type` being set to `application/json` in your HTTP request.

Comment: I cannot see Domains property in my graphserviceclient, Do I need to change any permissions for that?

Comment: The SDK isn't aware of permissions. Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK (see link in the answer).

Comment: I was not using the latest version of graph, but how do i keep up with version releases and properties released in a version?

Comment: If you install the library via Nuget, you can check for updates automatically.